# mvc3 ajax prepoluate textbox

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-3, data-binding

I have a controller that uses **ajax.actionlink** in order to get a partial view from another controller. My question is how can I use the **result from that ajax partialview to fill in a textbox in my main action** .

This is the **view i'm working on** corresponds to this view

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("Find location", "getzipcode",
new AjaxOptions
{
    UpdateTargetId = "ajax_insert",
    InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
    HttpMethod = "GET"
});

<div id="ajax_insert">

</div>

@using (Html.BeginForm("create", "service", FormMethod.Post))
{

    // fill Ajax code in this EditFor Result
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.zipcode)

}
```

as you can see above that ajax simply request's a partial view called **getzipcode** which just links to this action

```
public PartialViewResult getzipcode()
{
    var zipco = (from s in db.servicers where s.zipcode == 32839 select s);

    return PartialView("_review", zipco);
}
```

The ajax works correctly, im just stumped on inserting the zipcode into the EditFor box as well I tried
**@Html.EditorFor(model => model.zipcode,@ajax_insert)** but it did not work.

Comment: please do some work to make your code a bit more readable. There is entirely too much unnecessary space in your code snippets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*You can make use of `onSuccess` callback function*

```
    @Ajax.ActionLink("Find location", "getzipcode",
    new AjaxOptions
    {
        UpdateTargetId = "ajax_insert",
        InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
        HttpMethod = "GET",
        OnSuccess = "fillTextBox"
    });

    <script type="text/javascript>
     function fillTextBox(){
      //Use jquery to fill your text box
     }
    </script>
```